# Dana(Donation) to beggars at temples

Tags: puranas, belief, practice, worship

I heard that giving Dana after darshan will make the recipient(beggar) beneficial of getting punya of darshan but not the giver(devotee). Is there any purana which has guidelines on Dana. Is it ok to give Dana before or after the Darshan?

Comment: What really matters is the intention behind the donation/dana not what or how or to whom you donate.

Comment: "Is there any purana which has guidelines on Dana. " Yes almost every purana.You will find some guidelines in these answers- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17318/is-it-adharma-to-give-dana-without-considering-what-we-are-giving-and-to-whom-we

Comment: Related https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/27871/12304